# Is possible call a service inside a @Repository?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I´m new with java spring-mvc current I have a @Controller that call a @Repository and I want to use a @Service inside @Repository is it possible or what is the correct way?

I tried just put the Service inside of Repository

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/activa-servicio", params={"cupon"}, method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    @ResponseBody
    public String activaServicio(HttpServletRequest request,@RequestParam(value="cupon") String cupon) throws IOException {

        String json=publicDAO.activaServicio(cupon);

        System.out.println(json);
        return json;
    }

@Repository
public class PublicDAO {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    EmailService emailService;

 public String activaServicio(String cupon) {
  emailService.getActivationConfirmation();
}
```

I expect EmailService is fired, but current the EmailService display null exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EmailService` is null because you never set it. The `@Autowired` annotation only applies to `JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate`.

Also, field injection is discouraged, so your best bet is to use constructor injection. It's also less verbose.

```
private JdbcTemplate template;
private EmailService service;

@Autowired
public PublicDao(JdbcTemplate jt, EmailService es) {
  this.template = jt;
  this.service = es;
}
```